# Merge 3 lists with all match and unmatched data using c# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 lists in c#, 2 columns are same but 3rd column is diff..I need to merge all 3 lists into 1 list with all match and unmatched data..for ex.

ListA:
ID   Name value1

1. A.    10
2. B.    20
3. C.    30

ListB
ID.   Name.  Value2

1. ```
   A.      15
   ```
2. ```
   B.      40
   ```
3. ```
   D      50
   ```
4. ```
   E      60
   ```

List C
ID.   Name.  Value3

1. ```
   A.
   ```
2. ```
   B.      50
   ```
3. ```
   F.      60
   ```

Result would be

ID.   Name.  Value1.Value2. Value3

1. ```
   A.      10.   15
   ```
2. ```
   B.      20.   40.     50
   ```
3. ```
   C.      30.
   ```
4. ```
   D.            50
   ```
5. ```
   E.            60
   ```
6. ```
   F.                     60
   ```

Comment: Which ID value are you taking here? Or is ID just an index?

Comment: Id just an index, it's coming from database..so using it to check

Comment: In the result what should be the ID? In list B, the item D has id 3, list C has F with id 3. In result these have entirely different ids. Can you explain merge logic clearly?

Comment: We have 3 list..I'd and name column is same in all 3 lists..only last column value1,value2,value3 are diff..now we need to merge all 3 lists  with all match and unmatch records..lista has 3 rows, ListB has 4 rows and listc has 3 rows..now we need to display all records as output table mentioned

Comment: Please ignore id ..seems something is messed up for id..might be because of formatting

Comment: Are these lists of different types or all list contain same type with same field names?

Comment: It's same type only with same fields .only last column is diff in all lists..for lista -> value1..ListB -> value2, listc->value3

Answer (score 0):

You can use this class to merge the records.

```
 public class MergedItem
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? Value1 { get; set; }
        public int? Value2 { get; set; }
        public int? Value3 { get; set; }
    }
```

Then the records are combined, and finally, the result is grouped using LINQ in the following way:

```
        //Normalize data
        List<MergedItem> listM = new List<MergedItem>();
        listM.AddRange(listA.Select(r => new MergedItem() { Name = r.Name, Value1 = r.Value1 }));
        listM.AddRange(listB.Select(r => new MergedItem() { Name = r.Name, Value2 = r.Value2 }));
        listM.AddRange(listC.Select(r => new MergedItem() { Name = r.Name, Value3 = r.Value3 }));

       //Group data
        int index = 0;
        var mergedList = (
                        from item in listM
                        group item by item.Name into grouped
                        select new MergedItem
                        {
                            ID = ++index,
                            Name = grouped.Key,
                            Value1 = grouped.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == grouped.Key && i.Value1 > 0)?.Value1,
                            Value2 = grouped.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == grouped.Key && i.Value2 > 0)?.Value2,
                            Value3 = grouped.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Name == grouped.Key && i.Value3 > 0)?.Value3
                        }
                     ).ToList();
```

Hope you find it useful, regards.